# Creating an Outlook Signature file using VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Started VBA yesterday.

I want to create an Outlook Signature file where the signature has HTML formatting. I've succeeded in creating signatures, and transposing the desired information. I haven't been able to apply the desired format.

The final signature must have an image and a text division (kinda like a div, that has two divs inside and each use 50% width).

```
Sub Gerar_Assinatura()    
Rem INICIO SCRIPT VBS         
On Error Resume Next     

Rem VARIAVEIS PARA GUARDAR AS INFORMACOES     
Dim strNome As Range     
Dim strFuncao As Range     
Dim strOrgao As Range     
Rem Dim strCompany As Range     
Dim strAddress As Range     
Dim strAddress2 As Range     
Dim strpostalCode As Range     
Dim strPhone As Range     
Dim strExtensao As Range     
Dim strCell As Range     
Dim strMail As Range     

colorBlack = RGB(0, 0, 0)     
pickFont = "Calibri"     
pickSize = 11     

Set strNome = Range("O10")     
Set strFuncao = Range("O11")     
Set strOrgao = Range("O12")     

strCompany = "SNIPSNIP"     

Set strAddress = Range("O14")     
Set strAddress2 = Range("O15")     
Set strpostalCode = Range("O16")     

Set strPhone = Range("O18")     
Set strExtensao = Range("O19")     
Set strCell = Range("O20")     
Set strMail = Range("O21")     


Rem OBJECTO     
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")     
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()     
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection     
Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions     
With objSelection     

.TypeText "*html stuff and values SNIP*"

End With     
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature     
Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries     

Rem Cria o assinatura no Outlook     
Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()     
objSignatureEntries.Add "Snippy Snappy", objSelection     
objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Assinatura geral automatica"     
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Assinatura geral automatica"     
objDoc.Saved = True     
objWord.Quit     


Rem FIM SCRIPT VBS     
End Sub
```

This code works for text, images and font formatting, but I need the HTML to organize things properly.

Edit: I don't want to add or change the signature of the email being sent. I want to change/add the file where the signature is stored, which will be used as needed/intended.

Edit2: It's VBA, not VBS

Edit3: Desired outcome - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QMtm4Z4FnyOB6RUH6EnRywgL-XTzewpI

Comment: Are you sure that you are using VBScript and not VBA?

Comment: Now there's a question...

I'm not sure. I've been using both .VBS files and running Macros through Excel, which I assume is VBA.

Comment: If you need Excel, Word etc to write the code inside it is VBA. If it is in a *`.vbs` file it is VBScript. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970436.aspx

Comment: Edited the OP. Thanks Vityata :)

Comment: Can you also show what the desired outcome would look like?

Comment: Yes, I can!
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QMtm4Z4FnyOB6RUH6EnRywgL-XTzewpI

Found a way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Exchange Server or Office 365, it might be easier to have the signature get applied on the server-side because that way it's applied to **all** emails from mobile and web, not just Outlook.
You can use [Exclaimer Cloud Signatures for Office 365](https://www.exclaimer.com/exclaimer-cloud/signatures-for-office-365/?utm_source=SocialEngagement&utm_medium=Stackoverflow)

Or [Signature Manager for Exchange Server](https://www.exclaimer.com/signature-manager-exchange-edition/?utm_source=SocialEngagement&utm_medium=Stackoverflow)

I use them for myself and my clients - works a charm, set and forget!

Comment: I wasn't looking for alternatives - the issue was tackling this thing in VBA. Regardless, I swapped to Java and it's done already. Thanks for the reply.